KQL Sentinel and Invoke statement as a function
My query is as follows:
datatable (a:string) ["sad", "really", "sad"]
| invoke append_to_column_a(":-)")

My function is:
let append_to_column_a=(T:(a:string), what:string) {
    T | extend a=strcat(a, " ", what);
};
append_to_column_a(a,what)

I have a saved function as:

However, when I run the query I get:
append_to_column_a(): argument #1 must be a scalar expression
I'm not sure what's wrong, since if I add the function in front of it, the query runs just fine.
I also tried a few other ways and examples, and they all work find with the let statement above, but once you make it a function, it just breaks.

ensure that the function's signature matches the usage in your query.

Have you verified that invoke function is able to pass the data table directly! @Jason

@Jahnavi - can you explain more about that? That is new to me. I can call functions normal but is invoke function different?

@JayashankarGS - what do you mean by signature?

Can you remove append_to_column_a(a,what) from the function query and save it and then try! @Jason

Have you tried the below given approach. @Jason


append_to_column_a(): argument #1 must be a scalar expression:

After working on it, I found the issue is with the parameters passing to the callable function. There are few noted points related to the default values of user defined functions saving as a workspace functions.
Do not declare and pass the parameters while saving the query as a function as it is expecting a single scalar value for the first argument, instead it's receiving a table.
Below is the modified saved workspace function:
let append_ing = (x:string, what:string) {
    datatable (a:string) ["sad", "really", "sad"]
    | extend a = strcat(a, " ", what);
};
append_ing("['a',':']", ":-)")

Once it is done, I have executed below function in my sentinel workspace and was able to make it work successfully.
Query:
append_ing()


Reference: User defined types of functions
